# Async Data load with react redux persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I have a problem with async data. I have a component that handle data loaded from Server

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Col, Row} from 'antd';
import {persiststore} from "../../../../store";

class Step2Question extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
componentDidMount() {
    const questions = [];
    if (this.props.questions.length === 0) {
        this.props.callApi('GET', '/api/products/' + this.props.selectedProduct, null, this.props.token, (data) => {
            // this.setState({ranks: data.data});
            data.data.productQuestionModels.forEach(ele => {
                this.props.callApi('GET', '/api/questions/' + ele.questionId, null, this.props.token, (data) => {
                    questions.push(data.data);
                })
            })
        }, ...[, , ,], () => {
            this.props.addQuestions(questions);
            persiststore.flush().then(() => {
                this.props.disableNext(false);

            })
            persiststore.persist();
        }, 'questions');
    }
}

render() {

    return (
        <Row>
            {this.props.questions.map((ele, idx) => (
                <Col key={idx} style={{paddingTop: '30px'}} md={12} xs={12} sm={12}>
                    <strong>Question {idx + 1}: {ele.content}</strong>
                </Col>))}
        </Row>
    );
}
```

}

I dont know how to make questions load from sever render. If I use option `{pure: false}` in connect method it will render some items not all. Please help me thanks so much

Comment: try to use axios (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for make the request and look for async/await

Comment: I already used axios for it. This is the action I use through middleware

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I usually use React. If I have a component that I want to pull data, I set up an App-level state variable (array) to hold that data. Then I have an App level function that updates that array based on a passed array (using setState()). Then when I invoke the component, I send it the App-level array as well as that App-level function. Inside the subcomponent, I get the data into a local array, then I call the passed function with that array. In my render code of the subcomponent I refer to array passed from the App-level (not the local array I populated).

(note: in the pseudo code below, I use `...` to indicate your existing code would go here, or other code, etc)

**App level**

```
    state = {showQuestions: []}
    ...
    updateQuestions = (newQuestions) => {
        this.setState({showQuestions: newQuestions})
    }
    ...
    // then when you render (I'll assume the name of your component 
    // is Questions)
    <Questions 
        questionData={this.state.showQuestions}
        updatefunc={this.updateQuestions}
    />
```

**Sub-Component file** (inside the code you have above)

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    // use your code above, I'm assuming you are putting data 
    // into the questions array
    ...
    // after you've got the questions array all set up with all data
    this.props.updatefunc(questions)
    ...
}
...
// now down in the render of your Questions component
render() {
    return(
        ...
        this.props.questionData.map(... <your other code))
        ...
}
```

As a side note, in the React code I use I do not do a constructor function. The `this.props.` syntax is available without doing that. So maybe I am in a different version of React than you are. Also I'm not familiar with the `<'row'>` element you show in your `render()`. Therefore, I do not know if those things mean my examples above would function as expected or not. I recommend sprinkling `console.log()` statements around so you can see what data is passed where, etc. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The Row and Col I use is in antd library. It's just div with style. I already console.log(data) that I pass to Component. It always show nothing but if I click on expand button it show all items that passed to it. Because I think it stored in redux store already. So I dont want to put it to localstate of this component.